# Ubuntu-Server Linux ubuntu 5.13.0-1011-raspi

Tags: ubuntu

Установил систему вчера на аппаратуру Raspberry pi 4 model B. После запуска системы, делал всё последовательно из видео на YouTube, где человек обновлял пакеты apt update и устанавливал те , которых ещё не было. В настройке

Обязательно ли после Docker, нужно ставить Docker-compose?
Просто он у меня не устанавливается, я не понимаю в чём причина. Прописывал команды и с документации докер, и просто с репозитория Ubuntu. Не ставится.

Comment: Если вы не планируете использовать docker-compose, то не устанавливайте

Comment: Я даже пока не особо понимаю, для чего он нужен.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.